# How to solve undefined index in view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My array ($response_array) is like this :

```
Array
(
    [Auth] => Array
        (
            [UserID] => test
            [UserIP] => 123
            [XmlVersion] => Testing Version
        )

    [SearchAvailRequest] => Array
        (
            [CountryCd] => ID
            [CityCd] => JOG
            [CheckIn] => 2016-01-08
            [CheckOut] => 2016-01-09
        )

    [SearchAvailResponse] => Array
        (
            [Hotel] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [HotelNo] => 1
                            [HotelCode] => 321
                            [HotelName] => Test 1 Hotel
                            [RmGrade] => Deluxe
                            [RmGradeCode] => DLX
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [HotelNo] => 2
                            [HotelCode] => 212
                            [HotelName] => Test 2 & 1 Hotel
                            [RmGrade] => Deluxe
                            [RmGradeCode] => DLX
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to send the hotel data to view

So the view display data like this :

```
Hotel Name
Room Type
```

I try like this :

Controller :

```
  ...
   return view('frontend.hotel.main_list_hotel',[
  'hotel' => $response_array['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel']
]);
    ...
```

View :

```
    @foreach($hotel as $key=>$value)
{{ $key }}
{{ $value['HotelNo'] }}                     
@endforeach
```

But, there exist error like this :

```
ErrorException in TestController.php line 181: Undefined index: SearchAvailResponse
```

In localhost there is not an error. But there was an error in server

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is the data being retrieved different on local and live? Are you sure the `SearchAvailResponse` index exists on the server?

Comment: Where are you printing your array?

Comment: This seems to happen because the public ip on the server has not been registered to access the url api